# Problems with the physics interaction between two objects

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I want the upper yellow element to interact with the turquoise sphere. It should be put over it and when it comes back up it should return to its original shape.

When I try to use physics like soft body or clothing, it just deforms and falls down at the end, the object isnt following the animation anymore, as you will see in the second picture row.

What I can do to make the top element soft, felxible and smooth so that it fits over the other object and follows the shape of the sphere and how I reverse the effect so when the top object comes up it will return to its original shape.

How can i do that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Collision shapes , Your sphere has a Collision shape which is something not that corresponds to your collision shape in the second object , you can change this is Collisions > Collision shapes , there is an option that also allows you to make your mesh shape as your collision shape

Comment: Hm, do you mean that the ball needs to have physics collision switched on? It's definitely on. (Put some more picture in my request)

Comment: in the physics properties , where you have your rigidbody settings , there is a setting called collisions , there have a look at the shape of collision

Comment: As shown on the last picture collision is already assigned.

Comment: im not talking about these collisions , im talkin about the collision property of rigid body.........i get it , add a passive rigidbody in the object and add an appropriate collision shape to it